# Ubuntu 19.10 multiple monitors, wave issue displaying windows

Tags: multiple-monitors, 19.10

Using multiple monitors, I have the following issue.

Scenario:

> Ubuntu 19.10 upgraded from 19.04
>
> Laptop ThinkPad T440p over dock station
>
> 2 same monitors, Samsung (S24D390)

- 1st Monitor using mini display port (primary)
- 2nd Monitor using VGA port (either laptop's or dock's )

If all windows are in primary, all looks normal.

If you move one window to secondary start, the wave window effect occurs like this:

[image]

Also, the background gets a white/black screen instead of the one I have already set.

[image]

It is worth mentioning that after screen capture, the second screen gets as I said (withe/black); but, if you move window just a few on that screen, the behavior starts over again.

No idea about how to solve this issue, on 19.04, it was working flawlessly. Any tip is very welcome to troubleshoot this behavior I'm facing.

Also, if you use a third monitor, there will be the same behavior.

Comment: I wonder if this is a Thinkpad issue with 19.10. I'm facing the same thing with T480s and T490s. Both on upgrade and on clean install.

Comment: After latest packet updates, it seems is fixed this behave _(November 6th, 2019)_ or was when checking other desktop environment like _Gnome, Gnome Xorg, Ubuntu, Ubuntu Wayland_, and change back to Ubuntu.