# Ubuntu 19.10 laptop with external monitor - display issues (worked fine with 19.04)

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 19.10

I recently upgraded to 19.10 (had been using 19.04 happily for months).

I now have the following glitches when attaching my laptop (Dell XPS 9550 with nvidia graphics) to an external monitor via HDMI:

- Built-in display (laptop) switches to a black background (rather than the image I have set for background).  But the monitor gets the image background.
- Built-in display : windows leave images of themselves as you move them around.   But this does not happen on the external monitor
- Windows look blurry when moving them around on the external monitor

This post from a month ago seems to show (see its screenshot) and describe exactly the same problem.

[Ubuntu 19.10 multiple monitors, wave issue displaying windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184824/ubuntu-19-10-multiple-monitors-wave-issue-displaying-windows)

However that person says the problem went away after an update.  I've applied all updates, rebooted multiple times, etc -  been on 19.10 for about a week now.

Anyone have any ideas how I can resolve this?  At this point it's essentially unusable with an external monitor.

Additions:

When posting this, there was no /etc/X11/xorg.conf file.  Running nvidia-xconfig created this one:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 390.129  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-14)  Tue Jul 23 01:37:59 PDT 2019

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

And this is interesting:

```
jhouse@squan:~$ nvidia-smi 
Wed Nov 27 06:56:16 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 960M    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P0    N/A /  N/A |   1613MiB /  2004MiB |      5%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      3677      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            71MiB |
|    0      8046      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           631MiB |
|    0      8307      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         853MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
jhouse@squan:~$ 
jhouse@squan:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
jhouse@squan:~$
```

The laptop has both integrated intel graphics, and an Nvidia 960M

Comment: What's in your /etc/X11/xorg.conf ? You can try running nvidia-xconfig with plugged in monitor, this should generate config file for you in case it's missing or broken.

Comment: Thanks for responding. interestingly, I have no xorg.conf.    I'll try nvidia-xconfig next.

Comment: running nvidia-xconfig produced this output, and no difference in display behavior:  WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file.

Package xorg-server was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xorg-server.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xorg-server' found
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'

Comment: Also, if I switch the display configuration (using the Settings UI) to "mirror" the display, rather than "join", then everything looks/works fine.  When I set it back to "join", I get the same behavior of the laptop's built-in display being bad.

Comment: Also, it seems to make no difference whether I use the Nvidia driver, or the x.org nouveau driver.

Comment: Does Nvidia driver recognize your graphics card ? Try nvidia-smi to see if it shows up. Also post content of your newly generated xorg.conf file. And what graphics card you actually have ? Also post content of 'lspci | grep VGA'

Comment: Thanks again.  I edited the question/post to include those outputs.   Looks the Nvidia board is off?    The "additional drivers" panel shows that I am using NVIDIA driver 435  (I've also tried  390 and 430).

Comment: Not the laptop expert, but I assume your HDMI port goes into Nvidia card, not to integrated graphics somehow ? I had similar problem with multiple displays which I didn't solve. Basically if you want video output from Nvidia card and some other card simultaneously, you're screwed, at least with Nvidia drivers. Go to the BIOS and try disabling your on board graphics, then test everything again - reset xorg config, reboot etc.

Comment: Thanks again.  I hassled around with all those things to no avail.

Comment: I got it working again by doing a clean install of 19.10.   Something about the dist-upgrade process screwed up apparently.

Comment: I've seen the exact same but opposite, the same glitch happens on my *external display only*, Lenovo T460 :/